# Find the longest prefix for a table of tokenized strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithm, aggregation

I have a table (n < 100) with '#'-separated values in Postgres 13+. Sample:

```
id  value
1   'ABC#DEF#123#BAIT'
2   'ABC#DEF#156#BAIT'
3   'ABC#DEF#178#BAIT'
...
```

These values can be of any length (e.g. 'ABC#DEFDEF#GHIG#123123#456#678').
There are no NULL values.

I need the **longest prefix**. Entire tokens only, no partial match per token. Matching from the start of the string, and matching in all rows.

Result for the above sample would be:

```
id   output
1    'ABC#DEF'  -- or 'ABC#DEF#'
```

Another example:

```
id  value
1   'ABC#123'
2   'ADE#456'
```

Should return:

```
id   output
1    ''
```

Since the tokens 'ABC' and 'ADE' do not match completely, and should not return 'A'.

Currently I'm using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lcp_iterate(_state TEXT, value TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS
$$
    SELECT  SUBSTRING($2, 1, s - 1)
    FROM    generate_series(1, LEAST(LENGTH($1), LENGTH($2))) s
    WHERE   SUBSTRING($1, 1, s) <> SUBSTRING($2, 1, s)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  LEAST($1, $2)
    LIMIT 1;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

DO $$ BEGIN
    CREATE AGGREGATE lcp(TEXT) (SFUNC = lcp_iterate, STYPE = TEXT);
EXCEPTION
    when sqlstate '42723' then null;
END $$;
```

But it returns:

```
row  output
1    'A'
```

It would be extremely simple in any programming language, but I'm struggling to find a way to do it in Postgres.

PS: I'm trying to keep my code base as readable as possible so I'd like to avoid nesting 20 `CASE` items. (Since I can't have more than 20 '#'.)

Basic query to try:

```
WITH source AS (
  SELECT 'ABC#DEF#123' AS value
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ABC#DEF#456'
)

SELECT my_func(*) 
FROM source
GROUP BY value
```

Comment: For clarification, you are wanting this query to return the full substring if that substring has 2 or more instances after this column is split? Is that right? If so, I think it would look something like `SELECT token FROM source, unnest(string_to_array(value, '#')) token GROUP BY token HAVING COUNT(token) >= 2`

Comment: @JNevill Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I'm trying to give the minimum reproductible version of the problem but cropped it too much. I've just added precisions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, and `value` is defined `NOT NULL`, or you need to declare how to deal with `null` values (and do more).

#### [`RECURSIVE CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT id, string_to_array(value, '#') AS arr, 0 AS idx
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY id
   LIMIT  1
   )

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.arr, c.idx + 1
   FROM   cte c
   WHERE  c.idx < cardinality(c.arr)  -- end of string
   AND    NOT EXISTS (                -- mismatch
      SELECT FROM tbl t
      WHERE  t.id > c.id
      AND    t.value !~ ('^' || array_to_string(c.arr[1:idx+1], '#') || '(#|$)')  -- trailing '#' or end
      )
   )
SELECT array_to_string(arr[1:idx], '#') AS result
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY idx DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yMLGWYxU)

Pick the first row.
Then for every substring in `value` check if there is any other row that disagrees. Keep looping till the first mismatch or end of string.
The last iteration yields the longest common prefix. (For a single row it's the whole value.)

I formulated the predicate with a left-anchored negated [regex match (`!~`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to employ an **index (!!!)** - which is essential to make this scale. There are various candidates: a trigram GIN index, or a plain B-tree index with `COLLATE "C"`. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Or a more specialized (properly customized!) text-search index. See:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157982/3684)

In recent versions an SP-GiST index should work very efficiently too.

The beauty:

1. Can use an index, so the the size of the table matters little. I.e it scales excellently.
2. Stops work as soon as the first mismatch is found, and does not look at the rest, however long that may be.
3. Works for all corner cases.

The beast:

1. Added complexity from the rCTE.
2. The overhead won't pay for small tables with short strings. Test to find your sweat spot.

#### `string_to_table()` and count

```sql
SELECT string_agg(token, '#') AS result
FROM  (
   SELECT token, idx
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY idx) AS rn
   FROM   tbl, string_to_table(value, '#') WITH ORDINALITY AS a(token, idx)
   GROUP  BY token, idx
   HAVING count(token) = (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl)
   ORDER  BY idx
   ) sub
WHERE  idx = rn;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mgnHUygD)

This uses the same basic approach as [JNevill's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129017/939860). Fixes a corner case error and should be faster.

Unnest tokens into separate rows, remembering their position (`idx`). See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Aggregate tokens per position and only keep those that reach the total count. At the same time, take note of the `row_number()` for each qualifying position (`rn`).
Concatenate substrings after excluding positions past the first gap (`idx` > `rn` - see demo in fiddle!) to arrive at the longest prefix.

Should be faster than the first query for small tables and short strings. But scales with the number of rows x the number of positions in the string, i.e. poorly.

Related:

- [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43444/3684)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the exhaustive answer, very clear and all the links ! I'll have to take a look into performance, not sure which answer is faster.
Bonus point for the fiddle link which is more than I could've asked for :D

Comment: @Shraneid: Note that either query had corner case issues. I fixed mine, and also added a fixed set-based variant.

Answer (score 1):

Unnesting your delimited values is still a good option (updated from my comment for your more complicated requirements).

Consider:

```
WITH source AS (
  SELECT 'ABC#ABC#DEF#123' AS value
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ABC#ABC#DEF#456'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC#ABC#DEF#456'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC#ABC#DEF#456'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ABC#ABC#456'
)
, tokenization as (
    SELECT  
      token, 
      idx, 
      recordcount, 
      count(token) as tokencount
    FROM (SELECT count(*) OVER () as recordcount, source.* FROM source)
         ,unnest(string_to_array(value, '#')) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(token, idx) 
    GROUP BY token, idx, recordcount
    HAVING recordcount = count(token)
)
SELECT string_agg(token, '#' ORDER BY idx)
FROM tokenization
```

That `tokenization` cte is going to check the count for each token (each substring) with respect to its index (its location in the original string) and compare that to the entire record count for the table. Once that check is performed it will `string_agg()` your tokens back together in order of the index which will give you back the substring of the original strings that matches across all records.

Comment: this works perfectly ! thanks a lot, I'll take a look tomorrow in more details but this is what I was looking for !

Comment: The nice thing about this route is that it's a single table read and it's pretty adaptable. the single table pass coupled with some aggregation should make it pretty quick to execute. The downside is if you are coming from a procedural coding world, it takes some work to wrap your head around this as it's very set-based.

Comment: @Shraneid: Note the corner case error with matches in severed positions: https://dbfiddle.uk/yMLGWYxU I added a fixed variant to my answer.